# Persist hideshow folds between sessions?

Tags: elisp, hooks, code-folding

I use hideshow (`hs-mode`) in almost all languages. Most of the time, i keep function header lines visible but the body hidden like this,

```
function func(arg1, arg2){...}
```

So, every time I open the file, I do `C-c @ C-l` to hide the function body.  But, when I close emacs, these buffer states are gone and emacs open buffers without hiding the states.

Does any other lib support persisting show/hide info and reusing it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You, sir, are looking for [mode hooks](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Hooks.html): a set of functions that run every time you enter a buffer in a given mode.

Note that mode hooks will not *persist* state between sessions, but your question really appears to be about running the same command every time you enter a buffer in a given mode.

Now: for hideshow, the default binding `C-c @ C-l` is for `hs-hide-level`, whose docstring reads:

> `(hs-hide-level ARG)`
>
> Hide all blocks ARG levels below this block...

Rather than pick an `ARG` level (you'd probably want 1, I'd guess), you might consider `hs-hide-all`:

> `(hs-hide-all)`
>
> Hide all top level blocks, displaying only first and last lines...

Let's say you want to hide everything every time you open an `elisp` buffer.  Because the latter function does not require arguments, you could add it directly to a hook like so:

```
(add-hook 'emacs-lisp-mode-hook #'hs-hide-all)
```

If you wanted to use the former, you would need to write a specific function (the preferred method), or else wrap it in an anonymous `lambda` function:

```
(add-hook 'emacs-lisp-mode-hook (lambda () (hs-hide-level 1))) ; not preferred

(defun my-hs-hide-stuff ()
  (hs-hide-level 1))
(add-hook 'emacs-lisp-mode-hook #'my-hs-hide-stuff)
```

Comment: this answer is very helpful... the reason, i asked for persistent hide/show info is that, some function bodies that i am interested in can be left in show state.... but i can live with this... thanks, Dan...

Answer (score 0):

https://github.com/mrkkrp/vimish-fold has `persistence by default: when you kill a buffer your folds don't disappear` (there is also https://github.com/alexmurray/evil-vimish-fold for evil users)